# Blazor preview 9/mono-wasm memory access out of bounds: max string size for DotNet.invokeMethod?

Tags: .net-core, mono, blazor

Since dotnet core 3 preview 9, I am facing an issue invoking a dotnet method passing a large string from JavaScript.

Code is worth more than a thousand words, so the snippet below reproduces the issue. It works when `length = 1 * mb` but fails when `length = 2 * mb`.

```
@page "/repro"
<button onclick="const mb = 1024 * 1024; const length = 2 * mb;console.log(`Attempting length ${length}`); DotNet.invokeMethod('@GetType().Assembly.GetName().Name', 'ProcessString', 'a'.repeat(length));">Click Me</button>


@functions {
    [JSInvokable] public static void ProcessString(string stringFromJavaScript) { }
}
```

The error message is:

```
Uncaught RuntimeError: memory access out of bounds
    at wasm-function[2639]:18
    at wasm-function[6239]:10
    at Module._mono_wasm_string_from_js (http://localhost:52349/_framework/wasm/mono.js:1:202444)
    at ccall (http://localhost:52349/_framework/wasm/mono.js:1:7888)
    at http://localhost:52349/_framework/wasm/mono.js:1:8238
    at Object.toDotNetString (http://localhost:52349/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:39050)
    at Object.invokeDotNetFromJS (http://localhost:52349/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:37750)
    at u (http://localhost:52349/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:5228)
    at Object.e.invokeMethod (http://localhost:52349/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:6578)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (<anonymous>:2:98)
```

I need to process large strings, which represent the content of a file.

1. Is there a way to increase this limit?
2. Apart from breaking down the string into multiple segments and performing multiples calls, is there any other way to process a large string?
3. Is there any other approach for processing large files?

This used to work in preview 8.

Comment: Perhaps this link can help you: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/5617

Comment: Thank you @Isaac. That was one of the few related things I found doing my research before asking the question.

It doesn't seem to be related as the link is about max memory whereas this issue seems to be specifically about the marshalling of a string or object. Notice that 1 million chars work but 2 doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. Is there a way to increase this limit?

No (unless you modify and recompile blazor and mono/wasm that is).

> 2. Apart from breaking down the string into multiple segments and performing multiples calls, is there any other way to process a large string?

Yes, as you are on the client side, you can use the shared memory techniques. You basically map a .net `byte[]` to an `ArrayBuffer`. See [this](https://github.com/Tewr/BlazorFileReader/blob/58ae55a5c5737d08adf2350891eadbfe82a76bd9/src/Blazor.FileReader/script/FileReaderComponent.ts#L202) (disclaimer: My library) or [this](https://github.com/SteveSandersonMS/BlazorInputFile/blob/075a154d81192b588164608f9c381bece4d42f5e/BlazorInputFile/wwwroot/inputfile.js#L47) library for reference on how to do it. These examples are using the binary content of actual javascript `File`s but it's applicable to strings as well. There is no reference documentation on these API's yet. Mostly just examples and the [blazor source code](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/2de6c732d1f410460a627cb75aca91ae2c741fd5/src/Components/Web.JS/src/Services/Http.ts#L64).

> 3. Is there any other approach for processing large files?

See 2)

Comment: Thanks @Tewr. I came across your library the first time I faced this problem. However, I couldn't get it to work first in under 5 mins and I stuck with my poor-man's version.

Thanks a lot for your response. I'm giving you the correct answer :-)

Comment: Thanks @Tewr, I tried to modify your source code for my purpose. It turns out byte[] can't be communicated via JSON protocol now. https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/11244

Comment: It should emphasized that this answer only applies to client-side scenarios, there is no such thing as shared memory nor an equivalent for server-side blazor.

Comment: @code4j, to pass byte[] over JSON (which I assume would be a server-side blazor scenario), encode the bytes it to a base64 string. plenty of examples out there on this subject.

Answer (score 2):

I recreated your issue in a netcore 3.2 Blazor app (somewhere between 1 and 2 Mb of data kills it just as you described). I updated the application to netcore 5.0 and the problem is fixed (it was still working when I threw 50Mb at it).